# Invertible elements in a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R=\{\frac{2^km}{n}\mid k,n,m\in \mathbb Z, \text{ $k$ nonnegative, and $m,n$ odd }\}$ be a ring.  Find the units in the ring $R$.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl6qG.jpg)

Is it always when k is zero and m and n are same odd

Comment: Please take the time to click the edit timestamp to see how I was able to format your image with mathjax.  This edit contains a large percentage of basic things you should use to format your questions. Please avoid posing your questions as images, if possible. It isn't hard to learn. And if you don't bother, well, I guess people will quickly lose patience with you. So good luck.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "same odd." Do you mean "both odd"? A lot of people are going to read "same odd" and think you mean "$m=n$."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an invertible element $\frac{2^km}{n}$ of $R$. Then $\frac{2^km}{n}\cdot\frac{2^ca}{b}=1$. Hence,
$$\frac{2^{k+c}ma}{nb}=1\iff 2^{k+c}ma=nb$$
Whence, $2\mid nb$ if $k+c\neq 0$, which is a contradiction since $n,b$ are odd so $nb$ is odd. Hence, $k+c=0\iff k=-c$. But since $k,c$ are nonnegative, we must have $k=c=0$. So all the invertible elements of $R$ must be of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ with odd $m,n$.